# How to use LIKE in the middle of a string

Tags: php

How do I have LIKE check the month of the year registered in the database?

In the bank I have the column `date (date)` that registers the value in this format `2019-09-13`, I would like to know how to check with LIKE only the characters of the months `09`. What I tried was to use `substr`

```
WHERE data LIKE ?", array ( "%". substr ( $this->NumMes, 0, 5 )
```

Does anyone know any solutions?

Comment: i think you must select all the `date` and then substring all the results you got from that query and you have only the date's with a certain month number left over

Comment: We are assuming that your DB is MySQL, but just to be safe, could you confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Data by month use this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE MONTH(yourColumn) = '.substr ( $this->NumMes, 0, 5 ).'"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for data with month 9, you can simply use `Month(yourDateField)` :

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE Month(yourDateField) = 9
```

Or if you are looking for more than 1 month use `in` :

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE Month(yourDateField) in (8,9,10)
```